# How to print the the binary number on reversed form?

Tags: python-3.x

> This is a code of program to convert decimal number into binary...but the total answer printed is not in reversed form

```
num = 34
```

while num > 1:

```
remainder = str(num % 2)

num = num // 2
print(remainder[-1::-1], end="")
if num == 1:
    print(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your code is correctly converting from decimal to binary, which I can't verify because it's  not formatted correctly, here is a method to reverse an int.

```
def reverse(i):
    n = str(i)
    r = ""
    for i in range(len(n)):
        new = n[len(n)-i-1]
        r = r + new
    return r

print(reverse(124567))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the number to a string, reverse it, and convert it again to an int:

```
>>> int(str(12345)[::-1])
54321
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get binary of a number and reversed it, You can do this:

```
print("{0:b}".format(16)[::-1])
print("{0:b}".format(16)[::1])
```

**Output:**

```
00001
10000
```

> I hope this is what you mean. otherwise, I misunderstood